# How to create a code that tells two integers are co-prime?

Tags: java, primes

Write a method that, when passed two positive integers m and n, returns true if m and n are co-prime. Two integers are co-prime when they don't have any positive integer common divisor expect 1.

You can assume that m≤n.

```
public static boolean coPrime( int m, int n) { 
      if ( m%n == 0){ 
           return true; 
      } 
      return false;
```

}

Here is what I have so far. 
How do you realise that they are co-prime?

Comment: `return BigInteger.valueOf(m).gcd(BigInteger.valueOf(n)).equals(BigInteger.ONE);`

Answer (score 2):

You know two numbers are co prime if their GCD is 1.

Euclid's algorithm is pretty simple and straight forward for finding the GCD between two integers:

```
private int gcd(int p, int q) {
    if (q == 0) {
        return p;
    }
    return gcd(q, p % q);
}
```

So all you need to do is call this method with your two integers, something like the following:

```
private boolean coprime(int p, int q) {
    return (gcd(p, q) == 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* The running time of the function is O(m) - linear */

public static boolean coPrime( int m, int n) {

      /* Since m <= n */
      int index = 2;
      bool is_coprime = true;
      while(index <= m){
         if(m % index == 0 and n % index == 0){
             is_coprime = false;
         }
         index = index + 1;
      }
      return is_coprime; 
}
```

Comment: I assumed that m and n will be greater than 1. But if m and n can be equal to 1 then you can add the condition (index != 1) to avoid that case because both m and n will be divisible to 1.

Comment: You've neglected to increment `index` inside the loop, so you have an infinite loop. Also, no change is needed if m == n == 1 since by definition 1 and 1 are co-prime. Finally, this algorithm is very inefficient compared to the various variants of Euclid's algorithm. However, it is good example of what the OP should have come up with on their own as a first start.